# Fourier cosine series for a piecewise function

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying to expand the following piecewise function as a cosine series:

$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      3 & -7 < x < -1 \\
      8 & -1\leq x\leq 1 \\
      3 & 1 \leq x < 7 
\end{cases}
$$

The expansion should be in the form of:
$$
f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n\cos{\frac{n\pi}{p}x}}
$$

My attempt at a solution:
$$
2a_0 = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \ dx \\
2a_0 = \frac{2}{6}\int_1^7 3 \ dx + 2\int_{0}^1 8 \ dx \\
2a_0 = 22 \\
a_0 = 11$$

For $a_n$: 
$$
a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \cos{\frac{\pi nx}{L}} \ dx \\
a_n = \frac{2}{6}\int_1^7 3\cos{\frac{\pi nx}{6}} \ dx + 2\int_{0}^1 8\cos{\frac{\pi nx}{1}} \ dx \\
a_n = \frac{3\sin{\frac{7 \pi n}{6}}}{\pi n} - \frac{3\sin{\frac{\pi n}{6}}}{\pi n} + \frac{16\sin{\frac{\pi n}{6}}}{\pi n}
$$

However, my solution is incorrect.. and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you're doing wrong is that $L=7$ here, but you keep switching between using $6$ and $1$.  Another thing, that isn't really wrong, but klutzy, is that you're not taking advantage of symmetry.  You could use two integrals

$$\frac{2}{7}\int_0^1 \mbox{stuff} + \frac{2}{7} \int_1^7 \mbox{stuff}$$

instead of 3.

Comment: Shouldn't we find the even extension of the function first?Or do we assume the function is even in the range(-7,7)?

Comment: @Aladdin  Since the cosine series is asked for, we assume the function is even.